# Acentuação com formulário multipart/form-data e sql server usando ajax

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, asp

Olá.
Estou com um problema que está me tirando o sono. 
Estou trabalhando em código legado em asp clássico e preciso cadastrar um formulário que contém arquivo em pdf e dados (como nome, sobrenome) e outros campos. Quando a página é submetida para o servidor (iis8) através do evento submit do formulário, tudo corre bem e os campos são salvos no sql com os acentos de forma correta. No entanto, alguns arquivos são grandes e a resposta da página pode demorar um pouco, deixando o usuário sem saber o que está acontecendo. Passei a utilizar o ajax para fazer o submit e manter uma barra de progresso. O problema é que a acentuação não é persistida de forma correta no banco de dados. Já verifiquei a página salvar.asp no debug do firefox e a acentuação está correta. Fiz um response.write dos valores dos campos e tudo está acentuado de forma correta. Os dois arquivos (cadastro.asp e salvar.asp) estão com o mesmo encoding (Windows-1252). Já percebi que o "content-Length" quando postado pelo ajax tem 24 bytes a mais que quando postado apenas com o submit. Como resolvo esta situação? Alguém já passou por isto? Estou usando o componente jQuery Form Plugin (malsup dot com jquery form) para submeter o form via ajax.

Edit

Parece que isto é um problema do ADODB. Testei diversas formas de submeter os dados para o banco, todas utilizando o ADODB (com command, recordset, etc). Em todos os casos, quando uso ajax (pouco importa o plugin ajax para fazer isto - testei com ajax puro, [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) e jQuery File Upload Plugin) o ADODB encoda o texto que contém caracteres acentuados antes de enviar para o banco. Mas isto só ocorre com um submit com ajax. Quando o submit é o default, nada é encodado e tudo corre bem. Para resolver o problema, usei uma função encontrada aqui: https://support.persits.com/show.asp?code=PS130806188 e tudo está funcionando como deveria.
Para simplificar a resposta:
O arquivo cadastro.asp está salvo em utf-8. O arquivo salvar.asp está com a primeira linha assim:e <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE=1252%> e salvo em "Western European (Windows) - CodePage 1252". Sim, é estranho, mas está funcionando bem.
A função de encode/decode ficou assim:

```
Function Utf8ToUnicode(strText)
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Open
        .Charset = "Windows-1252"
        .WriteText strText
        .Position = 0
        .Type = 2 ' adTypeText
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        Utf8ToUnicode = .ReadText(-1) 'adReadAll
        .Close
    End With
End Function
```

Antes de submeter um campo que pode conter caracteres especiais, passo o valor que veio da página de cadastro para a função:

```
dim nome
nome = Utf8ToUnicode(request("txtNome"))
```

Comment: A página salvar.asp possui a tag "<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>" antes do restante do código?

Comment: Oi, Renato. O codepage para esta pagina é o 1252, que é a pagina de código para os caracteres acentuados. Sim, está na primeira linha de ambos os arquivos.